# An exercise about measure theory

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=(0,1)$, $\nu=\mathcal{L^1}$, $\mu=\#$ and $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}_1 \cap (0,1)$.

> Where the measure $\mu$ is defined as
>   \begin{equation}
> \mu(A)=\begin{cases}
> \# A \quad \text{if $A$ has finite cardinality} \\
> +\infty \quad \text{otherwise} 
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

Prove the following:

1. Prove that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite;

   > where $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite if exists a sequence $(A_h)_h\subset X$ such that $\bigcup_{h=1}^{\infty}A_h=X$ and for any $h\in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $\nu(A_h)<+\infty$.
2. prove that $\nu << \mu$ that is $\nu$ is absolutely conyinous with respect to $\mu$;

   > where $\nu << \mu$ if and only if $\mu(A)=0$ then $\nu(A)=0$.
3. Prove that it do not exists a measurable function $w \colon (0,1) \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ such that
   \begin{equation}
   \nu(E)=\int_{E}wd\mu,
   \end{equation}
   for any $E \in \mathcal{M}$.

For the first and the second point I have argued as following

1. We know that $(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ hence the cardinality of $(0,1)$ is the same of the real number hence I can found a sequence $(A_h)_h \subset (0,1)$ such that $\mu(A_h)=\infty$ for some $h\in \mathbb{N}$, hence $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.
2. We know that $\mu(A)=0$ only when $A=\emptyset$ but $\nu(\emptyset)=0$ because of definition. hence we can conclude that $\nu<<\mu$.

First of all I am wondering if my reasoning for the above part is right or I have to adjust it. Secondly, someone could help me with the third point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for the first two parts is right except that you should start with any sequence $(A_n)$ for the first part. You said you have found some $(A_h)$ and that does not prove that $\mu$ is not sigma finite. Anyway, the cardinality argument works.

For the last part take any point $x \in (0,1)$. Then $0=\nu (\{x\}) =\int_{\{x\}} w d\mu=w(x)$ since $\mu \{x\}=1$. Thus $w \equiv 0$ but then  $1=\nu (0,1)=\int_{(0,1)} w d\mu=0$ which is a contradiction.